# Application Installer abnormal process termination

Tags: android, titanium

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
Thu May 14 2015 10:23:15 GMT+0530
Operating System
  Name                        = Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise
  Version                     = 6.3.9600
  Architecture                = 32bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8468078592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 0.10.13
  npm Version                 = 1.3.2
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 3.4.2
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 3.5.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = D:\Programes\Titanium\titaniumsdk\mobilesdk\win32\3.5.1.GA
  Target Platform             = android
Command
  node C:\Users\sameera\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\titanium\bin\titanium --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt build --platform android --log-level trace --sdk 3.5.1.GA --project-dir E:\NavotarLatest --target emulator --android-sdk D:\Programes\Titanium\androidsdk --device-id titanium_1_WVGA800 --skip-js-minify --skip-js-minify
```

Can you help me with this. I have tried with LG G2 and with nexus 4 emulator. result is same. I feel like there is an compatibility issue in one of the dependencies.

Comment: dp copied from husnain profile :P

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30906078/2016932

Answer (score 3):

I got same issue many times and every time but i fixed my problem
with deleting titanium sdk and installing a newer version i know that maybe won't fix it but it works for me many times try to remove node.js also and if that didn't work you could try genymotion emulater and also you can drag the apk file into your device directly by the way you can do that also with genymotion emulator

Answer (score 1):

**In my case**, running with same nodejs version and Ti sdk version on mac, I found out there is an `incompatibility` between these 2 versions. so I downgraded Ti version to match nodejs version. problem solved.
or you could try installing,
 http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2015/03/titanium-sdk-3-5-1-ga-now-available-with-node-0-12-support/ 
*(p.s: windows doesn't give proper error massages for titanium debug as mac does)*